# Calling a django api from react for sign in page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have built a react application which has a login page. I am done with the frontend of login page using react. Now  the other person from my team has build a backend api on django. I want to call that api from my react code now. How should I do it? Do I need to learn something specific? I have searched in internet and all of the sources we to make serve react and django from same project. I have a React project with me and a separate api developed by someone else. Please guide me through this. I am pretty new to this.

Answer (score 0):

No, you dont have to learn something new. You need to just make an ajax call to the API endpoint from within your react application to fetch  or send the data needed and handle the response.

Also keep in mind to setup the ajax to send the CSRF token as shown in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/#ajax).

Comment: componentDidMount() {
        fetch(`http://localhost:8088/api/this/is/an/api/call`) 
            .then(result=> {
                this.setState({items:result.json()});
            });
    }             will this be suffice and work?

Comment: Yes, indeed. It will be sufficient

Comment: This should be sufficient for now. However, people tend to use something like Redux to make ajax calls and retrieve data and store data on the client side.